# How to generate multiple executable files in one Makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

My directory contains `2` source files: `a.c` and `b.c`. I want to generate executable file `a` from `a.c` and `b` from `b.c`. Now I can only figure out one method to write Makefile:

```
all:  
    gcc -o a a.c
    gcc -o b b.c
```

It seems a little awkward, is it better method?

Comment: What is awkward in this?

Comment: Just feel a little redundant, and wonder whether there is a better method or not.

Comment: It's not only *awkward*, it completely negates the concept of `make`. The same thing could be achieved by a simple shell script.

Answer (score 4):

The answers are fine, still I think you need some insight in how `make` works:

The basic functionality of `make` is to create output files from input files **if necessary**. `make` decides what is necessary by comparing timestamps: If any input file is newer than an output file created from it, the recipe for this output file is executed.

This means with just a rule named `all`, this rule is **always** executed (except when you happen to have a recent file actually *called* `all` -- to prevent this behavior, you have to list `all` as a `.PHONY` target, that is one that doesn't actually create a file). Your original Makefile is equivalent to a simple shell script, so it doesn't use `make` properly.

The minimal "correct" version of your Makefile should look like this:

```
all: a b

a: a.c
    gcc -o a a.c

b: b.c
    gcc -o b b.c

.PHONY: all
```

So, `all` is "phony" and depends on `a` and `b`. `a` is only rebuilt when `a.c` changed, `b` is only rebuilt when `b.c` changed.

In a real project, your programs are probably made from more than just **one** source file and in this case, you can really take advantage of `make`: Have it build *object files* of your translation units, so only the *parts* that changed are actually rebuilt. It's overkill for your tiny example, but could e.g. look like this:

```
a_OBJS:= a.o
b_OBJS:= b.o

all: a b

a: $(a_OBJS)
    gcc -o$@ $^

b: $(b_OBJS)
    gcc -o$@ $^

%.o: %.c
    gcc -c -o$@ $<

clean:
    rm -f *.o

.PHONY: all clean
```

You would just have to add more object files to `a_OBJS` and `b_OBJS` to include new translation units in your build. The *pattern rule* `%.o: %.c` will match them. There's a lot more to discover, I suggest starting with the [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

I think the follow method is better:

```
all: a b
a: a.c
  gcc -o a a.c
b: b.c
  gcc -o b b.c
```

In your version, `make all` will *always* run `gcc` twice, whether or not `a.c` and `b.c` are modified.  In this version `gcc` will be run only when necessary.

Of course you can use some magic (`for`-loop or similar) to create the rules but I think the difference between my and your method is clear.

Comment: You _could_ use magic, but with makefiles, I usually feel that simple and explicit is better than clever and barely-comprehensible (in makefiles, the space between ‘clever’ and ‘too clever by half’ is wafer-thin).  A pattern rule (`%: %.c` and `gcc -o $@ $<`) would be justified here, since it emphasises the symmetry.

Answer (score 1):

To me

```
all:
    gcc -o a a.c
    gcc -o b b.c
```

looks fine.
Or may be the following for better control

```
all: a b

a: a.c
    gcc -o a a.c

b: b.c
    gcc -o b b.c

clean:
    -rm a b
```

---

A lesser known trick to compile without `makefile`

```
make a    #run cc -o a a.c by make or
make b    #run cc -o b b.c by make
```

Or to generate both `a` and `b`

```
make a b
```

`make` uses implicit rule here, just like magic. **But prefer a makefile with rule specified**

Comment: `make a` or `make b` doesn't work. You don't have any rule how to create `a`. Just try it :)

Comment: I have tried it. Should work, that's the magical part. make expect `a.c` or `b.c` to exist and run an implicit rule. No need for makefile in this case