# Makefile to build multiple programs with Main in C

Tags: c, makefile

My goal is to create a makefile that can build 9 programs at once. Ex. Program1.c, Program2.c ... Program9.c.

Once I run make I hope to be able to type ./ProgramN (N being any program 1-9) to make any particular program run.

All programs share the same header file used for function prototypes and struct definitions, called programs.h. Also, all functions used by the 9 programs will be in a file called programs.c.

Can anyone give me a clue on how to do this?

Comment: `*.c` are not programs but source codes that cannot "run".

Comment: Define "at once". Do you mean sequentially or concurrently? Can you launch them as background processes using `&`? Each of these will need to be compiled first, then run. Does the failure of one to compile halt the whole process? Can you compile all of these into one executable?

Comment: I have a feeling that the OP just wants to compile 9 different source files into 9 executables.

Comment: You're on the right track, write a `Makefile` and then ask some questions if it's not working.

Comment: You're going to need to take some time to understand how the C compiler environment works and what's involved in linking executables when they have shared code.

Comment: Also, it would help to know exactly what you're going to do to produce nine different programs from the same source?  Will they have similar but slightly different functionality?  Or will they simply be nine copies of the same program?

Comment: How is this question related to this seemingly very similar one?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51355296/makefile-giving-duplicate-error-c/51355386#51355386

Comment: @Yunnosh - the post you pointed is from the same user!

Comment: @Yunnosch : It seems sufficiently different to me; there he was attempting to link multiple `main()`'s into one executable; learned from that question that cannot be none and what he actually intended is 9 independent executables.  It is probably fair to start a new question to figure our how to do that.  However the answer you linked is almost an answer to this question - except each executable only has one .c dependency.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45813030/how-to-generate-multiple-executable-files-in-one-makefile is probably a duplicate of this, asked somewhat more succinctly.

Answer (score 2):

You simply need a make with 9 targets - one for each fully linked executable, each with two components ProgramN.c and programs.c, where programs.c and ProgramN.c each have a dependency programs.h.

Something akin to the following (you need complete the `...` elided parts - and test the macros for your build environment and toolchain):

```
# Compiler, Linker Defines
CC      = /usr/bin/gcc
CFLAGS  = -Wall

.PHONY: all

# All targets rule
all : Program1 Program2 ... Program9

# Individual Program rules
Program1 : Program1.o programs.o
       $(CC) -o $@ $^

Program2 : Program2.o programs.o
       $(CC) -o $@ $^
...
Program9 : Program9.o programs.o
       $(CC) -o $@ $^

# Source file rules
Program1.c : programs.h
Program2.c : programs.h
...
Program9.c : programs.h
programs.c : programs.h

# Compile rule, (.c to .o)
%.o: %.c
       $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $*.c
```

Make has to build the pseudo target `all` to do that it finds a rule for each dependency, each of which link ProgramN.o and programs.o.  These .o files do not exist, so mak finds a rule to generate the .o files, there is a generic rule for translating.c to .o, so that is used.

Comment: What is `$(OBJ)`? Why is there no rule using `-o $@`?.

Comment: @Jens : copy & paste error collecting fragments form other examples - fixed (I think) - feel free to edit it, or post an answer of your own; this could easily be improved I think with enough make-foo, but probably best to keep it simple so the OP can see how it is works more easily.

Answer (score 1):

The actual makefile you need is quite small:

```
all: Program1 Program2 Program3 Program4 Program5 Program6 Program7 Program8 Program9

Program%: Program%.o programs.o
    $(CC) $^ -o $@

Program%.o: programs.h
programs.o: programs.h
```

**Done!** To understand how this works, you must start with the commands you would use to build these executables *without* Make:

```
cc programs.c -c -o programs.o
cc Program1.c -c -o Program1.o
cc Program1.o programs.o -o Program1
```

(Assuming you use cc as your compiler.) It makes sense to build the object files in a separate step (rather than just `cc programs.c Program1.c -o Program1`) because you can reuse `programs.o` with all of the executables 1-9.

To write this much as a makefile requires only one rule, not three, because Make already knows how to build `foo.o` from `foo.c`. But if you want Make to keep track of when files must be rebuilt, you must tell it which files these objects depend on. So you must specify rules for the object files even if you don't specify the commands in them:

```
programs.o: programs.h
Program1.o: programs.h
Program1: Program1.o programs.o
    $(CC) Program1.o programs.o -o Program1
```

You can make that last rule more concise with [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables):

```
Program1: Program1.o programs.o
    $(CC) $^ -o $@
```

And rather than writing versions of those least two for every program 1-9, you can write [pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules):

```
Program%.o: programs.h
Program%: Program%.o programs.o
    $(CC) $^ -o $@
```

Then just add one more rule (at the top, so that it's the default) that requires all of the programs:

```
all: Program1 Program2 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

With `gmake` [GNU make], the make can actually be fairly compact with a secondary expansion:

```
# mktgt/Makefile -- make file for mktgt
#
# SO: makefile to build multiple programs with main in c
# SITE: stackoverflow.com
# SO: 51387854

CFLAGS += -Wall
CFLAGS += -O2

ALL += Program1
ALL += Program2
###ALL += Program3
###ALL += Program4
###ALL += Program5
###ALL += Program6
###ALL += Program7
###ALL += Program8
###ALL += Program9

OLIST += programs.o
HDEP += programs.h

SRC = $(addsuffix,.c,$(ALL))
OBJ = $(addsuffix,.o,$(ALL))

all: $(ALL)

%.o: %.c $(HDEP)
    cc $(CFLAGS) -c $<

.SECONDEXPANSION:

$(ALL):: $$@.o $(OLIST)
    cc $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^

clean:
    rm -f *.o $(ALL)
```